# Why do we use structure, property or Enum syntax?

Tags: vb.net, syntax

I think it's substituable for just Dim, Public or others.

What is merit by using structure, property ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these things you mention have different purposes.

- [**Dim**](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/vardeclare.htm) is used to create a local variable, which only exists in the function (method) you declare it in.
- **Public** creates a member variable in a class. And it is accessible outside of the class.
- A structure is like a class, but the differences between structs and classes depend on the language. In .NET, structs are value types, where as classes are reference types. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289521%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more information.
- A property is like a public field, except it is modified through dedicated getter and setter 'functions'. These allow you to specify what is done with a value from a user, or how to calculate a value to return to the user.
- An [**Enum**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-vbnet) is just an organized collection of constants, with a related purpose.

I think you should have a good read through an introduction on Visual Basic .NET like one of these:

- http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvsnet/a/blecvbnet20101.htm
- http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/
- http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/CatalogVB.htm